Can't pass JSON API Data to Chart JS
Soo i am not so good with fetching data and i am lost and strugling with this couple days now -_- if anyone can help i appreciate it.
My code fetch and read data perfectly fine and pass it to html table but i cant pass it to the Chart... i am confused)
Here is my code
function loadReport() {
    
    var dateFrom = document.getElementById("date1").value.toString();
        var dateTo = document.getElementById("date2").value.toString();
        var apiurl = "<?php echo $user->getFromTable_MyId("integration_api", "users"); ?>";
        var pubID = "<?php echo $user->getFromTable_MyId("id", "users"); ?>";
    
        $.getJSON(apiurl + '&Target=Affiliate_Report&Method=getStats&fields[]=Stat.affiliate_info1&fields[]=Stat.payout&fields[]=Stat.conversions&fields[]=Stat.clicks&filters[Stat.affiliate_info1][conditional]=EQUAL_TO&filters[Stat.affiliate_info1][values]=pop_24&filters[Stat.date][conditional]=BETWEEN&filters[Stat.date][values][]=' + dateFrom + '&filters[Stat.date][values][]=' + dateTo + '&sort[Stat.date]=desc', function(data) {
     //if you want to add more on balance just enter number in value
     
     values9=[0]
     values8=[0]
     values7=[0]
    var data, id, conversion, clicks, payout, statDate = "";
    var id = '';
        var clicks = '';
        var conversion = '';
        var payout = '';
        
    for (i in data.response.data.data) {
        
       const chartDateArr = data.response.data.data[i].Stat.date;
        const chartClicksArr = data.response.data.data[i].Stat.clicks;
        console.log(chartClicksArr);
        const chartConversionsArr = data.response.data.data[i].Stat.conversions;
        const chartPayoutArr = data.response.data.data[i].Stat.payout;
                 
        
        statDate += "<table><tr><td>" + data.response.data.data[i].Stat.date + "</td></tr></table>";
    id += "<table><tr><td>" + data.response.data.data[i].Stat.affiliate_info1 + "</td></tr></table>";
    conversion += "<table><tr><td>" + data.response.data.data[i].Stat.conversions + "</td></tr></table>";
    clicks += "<table><tr><td>" + data.response.data.data[i].Stat.clicks + "</td></tr></table>";
    
    var num9 = parseFloat(data.response.data.data[i].Stat.payout);
    var num8 = parseFloat(data.response.data.data[i].Stat.clicks);
    var num7 = parseFloat(data.response.data.data[i].Stat.conversions);
    
    //This code will use percentage from db and read it here to reduce sum
    var percent = <?php echo '.' . $user->getFromTable_MyId("rev_percentage", "users"); ?>;
    var val = num9 - (num9 * percent);
    //this pushed data to values and calculate total sum
    values9.push(val)
    values8.push(num8)
    values7.push(num7)
    let total9=values9.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr)
    let total8=values8.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr)
    let total7=values7.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr)
    document.getElementById("onLoadConversions").textContent=total7;
    document.getElementById("onLoadClicks").textContent=total8;
    document.getElementById("onLoadsum").textContent='\u20AC ' + total9.toFixed(2);
    //#
    //#
    //#
    payout += "<table><tr><td> &euro; " + val.toFixed(2) + "</td></tr></table>";
    
    document.getElementById("statDate").innerHTML = statDate;
    document.getElementById("id_name").innerHTML = id;
    document.getElementById("conversion_name").innerHTML = conversion;
    document.getElementById("clicks_name").innerHTML = clicks;
    document.getElementById("payout_name").innerHTML = payout;
    
    //Chart code START
    if (myChart3) myChart3.destroy(); //this line will avoid chart error when calling  function again
var ctx3 = $("#line-chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: chartDateArr,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Revenue",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(40, 153, 51, .3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(40, 153, 51, .7)",
            data: chartPayoutArr
        },
        {
            label: "Clicks",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)",
            data: chartClicksArr
        },
        {
            label: "Conversion",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(161, 21, 21, .3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(161, 21, 21, .7)",
            data: chartConversionsArr
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
});

//Chart code END
    
};
});
    
    
    
}

Here is SS of results outputs:
chart
table
console
Here is JSON text result from API fetch:


{
  "request": {
    "Target": "Affiliate_Report",
    "Format": "json",
    "Service": "HasOffers",
    "Version": "2",
    "api_key": "de52d0645f23810a3c6c8e470d3ae678f6bac643b2ed4a835328e22d368b7d0d",
    "Method": "getStats",
    "fields": [
      "Stat.affiliate_info1",
      "Stat.source",
      "Stat.affiliate_info5",
      "Stat.affiliate_info4",
      "Stat.affiliate_info3",
      "Stat.affiliate_info2",
      "Stat.payout",
      "Stat.conversions",
      "Stat.clicks"
    ],
    "filters": {
      "Stat.affiliate_info1": {
        "conditional": "EQUAL_TO",
        "values": "pop_24"
      },
      "Stat.date": {
        "conditional": "BETWEEN",
        "values": [
          "2024-02-01",
          "2024-04-15"
        ]
      }
    },
    "sort": {
      "Stat.date": "desc"
    },
    "_": "1713208372551"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "page": 1,
      "current": 50,
      "count": 7,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "data": [
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "7",
            "date": "2024-03-04"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "27",
            "date": "2024-03-03"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "72",
            "date": "2024-03-02"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "2653",
            "date": "2024-03-01"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "1",
            "date": "2024-02-29"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "11",
            "date": "2024-02-28"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "6",
            "date": "2024-02-26"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
}




can you add to your question the data json, as text? creating a [mre] would make it easier to answer

ok i edited my question and added JSON result from my API, hope it will help.

Pay attention your chart generation is within the loop of the data. That's why the datapoints are single numbers instead of arrays. You need to take the chart out of the loop, and feed it with the arrays of the respective data (using map for example).


const data = {
  "response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "page": 1,
      "current": 50,
      "count": 7,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "data": [{
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "7",
            "date": "2024-03-04"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "27",
            "date": "2024-03-03"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "72",
            "date": "2024-03-02"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "2653",
            "date": "2024-03-01"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "1",
            "date": "2024-02-29"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "11",
            "date": "2024-02-28"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "affiliate_info1": "pop_24",
            "source": "",
            "affiliate_info5": "",
            "affiliate_info4": "",
            "affiliate_info3": "",
            "affiliate_info2": "",
            "payout": "0.000000",
            "conversions": "0",
            "clicks": "6",
            "date": "2024-02-26"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const chartDateArr = data.response.data.data.map(item => item.Stat.date);
const chartClicksArr = data.response.data.data.map(item => +item.Stat.clicks);
const chartConversionsArr = data.response.data.data.map(item => item.Stat.conversions);
const chartPayoutArr = data.response.data.data.map(item => item.Stat.payout);


//Chart code START
var ctx3 = $("#line-chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: chartDateArr,
    datasets: [{
        label: "Revenue",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(40, 153, 51, .3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(40, 153, 51, .7)",
        data: chartPayoutArr
      },
      {
        label: "Clicks",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(127, 127, 127, .3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(127, 127, 127, .7)",
        data: chartClicksArr
      },
      {
        label: "Conversion",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(161, 21, 21, .3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(161, 21, 21, .7)",
        data: chartConversionsArr
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});

//Chart code END
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>

<div>
  <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</div>




You was right about loop and also i used date.push(data.response.data.data[i].Stat.date);
in loop so that fixed my code.
Thank you man, best regards <3
